# Making a private github's wiki public

Tags: git, github

So I have a private repository on GitHub but would like to make the Wiki public so anyone can see it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it has nothing to do with coding but just using the settings) or direct to GitHub:Support

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fork the repository, delete all contents by creating a new orphan master branch, force-pushing master and pruning all other branches, make the fork public.

Alternatively, create a new empty repository, create a dummy wiki page on that new repostitory, check out the wiki of the old repository and push it to the new:

```
git clone git@github.com:user/old-repo.wiki.git
cd old-repo
git remote add new git@github.com:user/new-repo.wiki.git
git push -f master new
```

Both these solutions result in two repositories: The old, private one that contains the data, and the new public one with the wiki.  You can then delete the old wiki.

Comment: If I do this, and I update the wiki on the private repo, will it get pushed to the public wiki?

Comment: @WilliamHodges: No, it won't.  Just delete the old private wiki, or replace it with a single page redirecting to the new one.

Answer (score 5):

Best thing I found was that Github pages now gives you an option to publish from a "docs" folder:

[image: Github pages options]

You could copy the wiki files there, or get fancy, and setup a submodule in that directory that would pull from the wiki repo associated with the primary repo. But don't forget that anything in this folder will now be public, which is good if you want to expose the wiki, but bad if anyone decides to put some other kinds of "docs" in there-